# Android Application Crashes on version 6 (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, crash, dropbox-api

I am building an Android Application with API 23. But on Marshmallow, my app gets crashed as it launches. The error message I got is as follows:

```
E/DropboxRealtime: null InputStream java.io.IOException: null InputStream 
at xjr.a(:com.google.android.gms:187) 
at xjr.b(:com.google.android.gms:131) 
at xiw.a(:com.google.android.gms:88) 
at        com.google.android.gms.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedChimeraService.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms:1180) 
at bhe.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms:65)                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Also to let you guys know that I am not using any Dropbox api in my code. Then why its saying E/DropboxRealtime?

Comment: This doesn't look like the stacktrace from your app.

Comment: Which all permissions does your application requires

Answer (score 0):

If you are building an Android Application as **targetSdkVersion 23** And running on **Marshmallow** then You have to give permissions in That activity where that permission needs.If you want to avoid crashes either you make **targetSdkVersion 22** or give runtime permissions in respected activities.

Answer (score 0):

I had come across this error. 
In my code there is an intent.putExtra(,null)

Code:
`Intent intent=new Intent(this, ZoneActivity.class);`
`intent.putExtra("USER",getIntent().getExtras().getString("USER"));`
`startActivity(intent);`

problem was getIntent().getExtras() is null

I had replaced it and its working.